# geo-spacial density based clustering

Tags: sql, database, cluster-analysis, geospatial, computational-geometry

I'd like to cluster/break down users into groups of 10-100 on a map with non-overlapping geo boundaries for each cluster.

What kind of database and query could I use to calculate that?  Should I just use any database and use some sort of map reduce algorithm to calculate the clusters?  Would something like a k-means clustering algorithm be useful here?

Can I do this with a query rather than a map reduce?

Comment: Why don't you **try it and come back with a precise question**? Questions like this attract opinionated answers and spam, as they cannot be answered objectively. K-means is worth a try, but I woudln't use SQL. I would also try DBSCAN and OPTICS clustering, as well as Canopy preclustering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a voronoi diagram. A voronoi diagram is the dual of a delaunay triangulation with some useful properties: https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/nearest-neighbours-voronoi-diagrams-and-finding-your-nearest-sql-server-usergroup.